# SOQL Help with DateTime attempting to populate package.xml

Tags: soql, datetime

I am trying to Create a SOQL search to retrieve the FolderName, ReportType and DeveloperName from all reports ran from Jan 1, 2021.  Here is my current search.

```
SELECT Name, FolderName, DeveloperName, ReportType, LastRunDate FROM Report WHERE LastRunDate => 2021-01-01T0800
```

I am receiving 'Unknown error parsing query'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass Datetime in the format like`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ` this one, for example, if GMT time suits you. Here are [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) that explain in which format you can use Datetime in SOQL queries. Also it is `>=`, not `=>`.

```
SELECT Name, FolderName, DeveloperName, LastRunDate FROM Report WHERE LastRunDate >= 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

And there is no such field `ReportType` on `Report` sObject. However, you can retrieve Report type with `Reports` classes, but for each report ID separately:

```
Id REPORT_ID = '00O...';
Reports.ReportDescribeResult result = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(REPORT_ID);
Reports.ReportMetadata reportMetadata = result.getReportMetadata();
Reports.ReportType reportType = reportMetadata.getReportType();
System.debug(reportType);
```